# Partial differentiation in transformed coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, coordinate-systems

Following [lecture notes from MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/earth-atmospheric-and-planetary-sciences/12-950-atmospheric-and-oceanic-modeling-spring-2004/lecture-notes/lec25.pdf) it says that, given some variable $A = A(x, y, z(x, y, r, t), t)$ where $r$ is a transformed vertical coordinate

$\left. \frac{\partial A}{\partial x} \right|_r = \left. \frac{\partial A}{\partial x} \right|_z + \frac{\partial A}{\partial z} \left. \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right|_r $

I can see this works by trying concrete examples, and I think I can see the second term on the right is due to the chain rule (because $A$ is a function of $z$ is a function of $x$).  But where does the first term on the right come from?   Is it because $A$ is also a function of $x$ explicitly?  Can someone point me to a piece of theory that underpins this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the confusion comes from transforming from $(x,z) \rightarrow (x,r)$. These 2 $x$s are not the same in terms of partial derivatives because, the first assumes that $z$ remains constant and the second assumes that $r$ remains constant. So if instead we were to start with:
$$A(x(x^\prime), z(x^\prime,r))$$
Then the chain rule would give us:
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^\prime}
 =\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial x^\prime}
 +\frac{\partial A}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x^\prime}$$
where what you previously wrote as
$\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\big\bracevert_r$ is now written $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x^\prime}$ and what you previously wrote as $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\big\bracevert_z$ is now written as just $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}$. And of course $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^\prime}=1$

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  There's also a $\frac{\partial A}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$, but since that's zero, it's omitted.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'm more looking for a pointer to the theory for why this is the case (preferably without getting into jacobians or tensors!) so that I can convince myself.

Comment: @hertzsprung:  It's all about the (multivariable) chain rule.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html

Comment: The wolfram link helps, but it looks like the subscripts of $u$ are not consistent... is it $u_i$ or $u_j$?  Also, how do $m$ and $n$ correspond to $i$ and $j$, and why do we need two pairs of letters?

Comment: @hertzsprung:  $i$ and $j$ are placeholders -- two uses of $i$ need not be related (although it is good didactic practice to make them related).  At the MathWorld article, the subscript $i$ only appears on $u$ and therefore is ranging over $[1,p]$.  The subscript $j$ only appears on $x$ and therefore ranges over $[1,n]$.  We need these letters because the chain rule applies to one or more (outermost) dependent variables (the $\{y_i \mid i \in [1,m]\}$) which depend on dependent variables (the $\{u_i \mid i \in [1,p]\}$) which depend on independent variables (the $\{x_i \mid i \in [1,n]\}$).